# Cannot drop or create table

Tags: postgresql-8.2

I've got a problem with a database here, in which after one update on the database one table stopped working.
What i can't do (Considering table xxx):
Dump whole database; (it says that the table doesn't exist)

```
SELECT * 
FROM xxx;   (it says that the table doesn't exist)

CREATE TABLE xxx(id int); (it says that the table exists)
```

I can't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: could you please add a bit more background on this issue. Does it show up on you schema, for example? Also, did you read/see [this?](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3973.1366218935@sss.pgh.pa.us)

Answer (score 0):

The Table Appears when you do a show tables?

```
mysql> show tables
```

Have you tried restart the mysql service?